# What is the APPCMD.EXE syntax to remove all IP Address and Domain Restrictions from a website?

Tags: iis

I have the syntax to add the initial Restricted IPs.  I just need syntax to remove all IPs for automation purposes.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "ParentSite" /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /allowUnlisted:false /commit:apphost
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "ParentSite" /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /+"[ipaddress='192.168.1.100',allowed='true'" /commit:apphost
```

I do know setting allowUnlisted to true effectively accomplishes my underlying goal.  I just want things to be clean in IIS.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe clear config "ParentSite/ChildSite" /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /commit:apphost
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "ParentSite/ChildSite" /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /allowUnlisted:true /commit:apphost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an additional parameter ("delete") you can add to the "clear" command to force IIS to remove the section as well as clearing the contents of it;

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe clear config "ParentSite/ChildSite" /delete:true /section:system.webServer/security/ipSecurity /commit:apphost
```

I've tested this on server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5, but it also exists on versions at least as low as server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5